# Right Click, Create PDF

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, print-to-pdf, cutepdf

I spend a lot of time using a PDF printer to "print" documents into PDF's... Is there a program that includes Explorer functionality to "Create PDF" via right click, context-menu?

This would, I hope, be the equivalent of "Open file" > "Print" > "Choose PDF Printer" (aka CutePDF) > Save as file with same name as DOC/XLS/...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDFCreator does this - it opens the relevant app, does the print to PDF and closes the app..

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/

[image]

Comment: Must be the only "PDF Printer" I haven't tried (CutePDF, PDF24, doPDF, PDF9895, etc). Trying it now.

Comment: The context menu works... the problem is it pops up with a "save as". Doesn't seem to have the option to "auto create new pdf, same directory, same name". This would be trading one set of clicks (open with word > print to "CutePDF" > save as) with another set of clicks (right click > save as > change to current directy). It does have an Auto Save feature that saves to a specific directory (not current directory).

Comment: http://www.pdfforge.org/content/auto-save-mode also "The last piece of the puzzle is setting up Auto-save in PDFCreator itself.  Run "PDFCreator Settings" from the start menu and click the 'Auto-save' link on the left side of the window. "